# Maxmind GeoIP - How to identify requests from Google, Yahoo or Bing bots to avoid redirects

Tags: geoip, maxmind

We redirect the customers to country specific website based on the country returned by the Maxmind APIs. But due to this when the requests come from the search engine bots, which can have any IP based on the country where bot runs from, those requests are also being redirected to respective country specific sites. For e.g. bot running from US is unable to crawl UK site as the request is redrcted to US site. Due to this bots are unable to crawl the targeted website, rankings are getting affected and country specific sites are not shown on top when the search is done from country specific Google domain such as co.uk. We can add logic to handle this scenario. But in future when new IP ranges are added by the bots or any new bots are introduced, we need to update the code again. Hence this approach doesn't look feasible. Is there any better way that Maxmind recommends to handle such exceptions?

Comment: Why don't you by pass the redirection if the IP address is from Search Engine? You can export the list here http://www.ip2location.com/free/robot-whitelist

Comment: @Michael - Thank you for sharing the URL.

Comment: @Michael -  In my case the Maxmind redirection logic is in the application code. The next obvious question will be why do I need any application logic for handling redirects. In case a user from one country (say USA) explicitly wants to access the website of another country (say UK) - site has a option to change the country - I should allow them to do so. In this case irrespective of the IP address I should let the request go to another country's website.

Comment: @Manetsus - Yes, I did Google to get the solution. As I couldn't find the answers I raised the question here.